# Add\Modify a file in WindowsInstallerEditor (WISE)

Tags: windows-installer, wise

How can I modify an existing file in Windows Installer Editor. When I tried to add it through `FeatureDetails -->Files --> AddFile`, it is still taking the old file with less size.

Should I remove the existing from the installer before adding. If so, how to remove it?

Comment: Is this an MSI that you got or one that you built yourself? It appears that you have obtained an MSI file that you did not build, but you want to change a file it will install? Why are Wise and Advanced Installer tagged?

Comment: This is the MSI i am going to build using WISE. I want to modify an already added file in it. When i add it through FeatureDetails -->Files --> AddFile and newly created msi is still installing old file

Comment: It has been a while for me since using Wise, but when you add a 'file' to a component object in Wise, you are adding a file path reference, so that at compile time, it looks at the path and grabs whatever file version you have referenced. Check the physical file location for the reference to see why it is not the version you expect.

Answer (score 0):

At last i was able to find a solution for this issue. Actually file was not getting installed from the MSI, but it was getting installed from the MergeModule that was also getting installed while installing the MSI. So i had to modify my file in the MergeModule and rebuild the MSI again  fixed the issue.